# Python Opengl Texture Repeat

Tags: python, opengl, textures, repeat, pyglet

I am a beginner in opengl. I am trying to repeat the texture on the GL_QUADS.

So far Here is the code for loading the texture,

```
    file = os.path.join('image','texture.png')
    surface = image.load(file)

    self.t1 = surface.image_data.create_texture(image.Texture)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t1.id)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

and drawing

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.t1.id)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(self.width, 0,  0)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(self.width, self.height, 0)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(0, self.height,  0)
    glEnd()
```

When self.width and self.height are changed, the texture is stretched and distorted.

How can I repeat the texture?
Pardon me if i did wrong.

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I repeat the texture? Pardon me if i did wrong.

By using texture coordinates (glTexCoord) outside the range [0,1].

Comment: Thanks , But why is it like [this](http://f.cl.ly/items/2q2R1y0x3d2b2P0Q4300/Screen%20Shot%202011-11-02%20at%203.37.19%20PM.png) when I try 3.0 instead of 1.0?

Comment: @MichelleChan: OpenGL-1 had the constraint, that texture image dimensions had to be powers of 2. This limitation has been lifted since OpenGL-2, but some toolkits may still apply padding rows and/or columns to make a texture power of 2 sized. Try using a texture of say 512×256 pixels.